# Prove: $(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$ Over A Field

Tags: algebra-precalculus

let $0\neq a\in \mathbb{F}$ 
Prove: $$(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$$

I have tried to start with the definition of an inverse, For all  $0\neq a\in \mathbb{F}$  we have:

$$a\cdot a^{-1}=a^{-1}\cdot a=1$$ But could not find a way to continue (tried multiplying by  $(a^{-1})^{-1}$

Comment: What is $\mathbb{F}$, a ring, a field, or still something else?  You'll start understanding mathematics when you always start with a definition.

Comment: @ProfessorVector it is a field

Comment: Definitions belong into the question, not into some comment.

Comment: I know that the assumption of being in a field is common, but this can be weakened to a division ring, where multiplication is not necessarily commutative.

Comment: @newhere  Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 5):

$$(a^{-1})^{-1}(a^{-1})=1\implies (a^{-1})^{-1}(a^{-1})a=(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$$

Comment: $$(a^{-1})^{-1}(a^{-1})=1\implies (a^{-1})^{-1}(a^{-1})a=(a^{-1})^{-1}a=a$$

Comment: @GNUSupporter yes! I fixed the typo meanwhile! thanks

Comment: But how can I know that $(a^{-1})^{-1}$ is the inverse of $a^{-1}$?

Comment: Is that not what the inverse notation means? They always exist, are unique, so that's how we denote it.

Answer (score 5):

By definition of the inverse the identity $a \cdot a^{-1}=a^{-1} \cdot a=1$ implies that $a$ is the inverse of $a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
a&=1\cdot a\tag{definition of 1}\\
&=((a^{-1})^{-1}\cdot (a^{-1}))\cdot a\tag{definition of inverse}\\
&=(a^{-1})^{-1}\cdot ((a^{-1})\cdot a)\tag{associativity}\\
&=(a^{-1})^{-1}\cdot 1\tag{definition of inverse}\\
&=(a^{-1})^{-1}\tag{definition of 1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

There are several correct answers here. I will try another, using more words, in hopes of making things clearer.

By definition, the inverse of an element $a$ is the thing you multiply $a$ by to get $1$. Suppose the inverse of $a$ is $b$. That means $ab = 1$. So $a$ is what you multiply $b$ by to get $1$ so $a$ is the inverse of $b$. Inverses come in pairs, e.g. $2$ and $1/2$ in the rational numbers.

Now if you choose to name the inverse of $x$ with the notation $x^{-1}$ then it follows from the previous statement that $(a^{-1})^{-1}= b^{-1} = a$.

Since you are working in a field, you do not need to worry about whether 
an inverse exists or is unique or works with multiplication in either order. Those complications come up in other algebraic structures.

Answer (score 0):

Since a has an inverse then we have 
          $$a•a^{-1}=a^{-1}•a=1$$
Then we  just replace a by b to get 
        $$ b•a^{-1}=a^{-1}•b=1$$
Which gives us that b is actually the inverse of $a^{-1}$

Thus: $$ b={a^{-1}}^{-1}$$
Hence done.
Hope it helps

Comment: Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You may enclose the part for the superscript by `{...}`, like `a^{(-1)}` for $a^{(-1)}$.

Comment: Thnx i did it hope it's fyn know